Why is my Google oAuth Application getting rejected for "The request has been classified as abusive and was not allowed to proceed"?
I've seen a few threads on the same topic, but nothing worked for us. I go to submit our application with our actual app name, plus I've tried our ID, and I get this error
An error saving your app has occurred
The request has been classified as abusive and was not allowed to proceed

Nothing relevant in Network Tab.
I've applied with the name "Quickstart" and it got rejected for not being my app name.

Has anyone got around this?

Have you tried creating a new project and using that for your application to see if the same error message shows up?

I've just submitted a new application now. Will let you know how that goes
